# Setting Yearless Birthday in CNContact class with Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How do you set a new Contact with a yearless birthday with Xamarin iOS?

[iOS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html) states you can just leave the NSDateComponent.year field blank for a yearless birthday.

After trying this in Xamarin iOS, it bugs out the birthday field on the New Contact UI, making it unusable.

```
var store = new CNContactStore();
var contact = new CNMutableContact();

// construct birthday w/o year
var birthDate = new NSDateComponents();
birthDate.Month = 11;
birthDate.Day = 12;
contact.Birthday = birthDate;

// pop iOS Contact UI
var editor = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact (contact);
editor.ContactStore = store;
editor.AllowsActions = false;
editor.AllowsEditing = true;
navcontroller.PushViewController(editor,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to set the calendar in the NSDateComponents to Gregorian.

```
var store = new CNContactStore();
var contact = new CNMutableContact();

// construct birthday w/o year
var birthDate = new NSDateComponents();
birthDate.Calendar = new NSCalendar(NSCalendarType.Gregorian);
birthDate.Month = 11;
birthDate.Day = 12;
contact.Birthday = birthDate;

// pop iOS Contact UI
var editor = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact (contact);
editor.ContactStore = store;
editor.AllowsActions = false;
editor.AllowsEditing = true;
navcontroller.PushViewController(editor,true);
```

Comment: That would be an iOS bug, but as long as you are not releasing your app internationally that would work, should file a bug : http://radar.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the contact first, then the iOS Contact Editor can handle the year-less date correctly.

```
var store = new CNContactStore();
var contact = new CNMutableContact()
{
    GivenName = "Stack",
    FamilyName = "Overflow"
};
var birthDate = new NSDateComponents();
contact.Birthday = new NSDateComponents()
{
    Month = 11,
    Day = 12,
};
######
var saveRequest = new CNSaveRequest();
saveRequest.AddContact(contact, null);
NSError error;
store.ExecuteSaveRequest(saveRequest, out error);
######
var editor = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact(contact);
editor.ContactStore = store;
editor.AllowsActions = false;
editor.AllowsEditing = true;
PresentViewControllerAsync(editor, true);
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach wouldn't allow the user to check for what information is being added and give the opportunity to edit any fields before committing.